# Dynamic FormRequest Validation (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to create a dynamic FormRequest validation in my function? See sample code below.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Model::create($request->all());
    return redirect(url('/'));
}
```

What I mean is that I will change the "Request" parameter to the variable $formRequest.

My goal is that I would like to create different validation rules for a dynamic set of data of a single model.

If I could achieve this with other ways, please let me know. Thank you!

Edit:

Sample scenario:
I have a form that has fields of First Name, Middle Name and Last Name.

First Rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'middlename' => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Second Rule:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Where in the second rule only requires first and last name.

I just want to know if there are other ways of doing this rather than creating multiple store methods and adding more routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skipping `FormRequest` and using the `validate` method on the `$request` instance can achieve this. [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-5/episodes/2) even has a lesson on it.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $rules = [/*...*/];

    $attributes = $request->validate($rules);

    Model::create($attributes);

    return redirect(url('/'));
}
```

Comment: This is what I have in mind but if possible, I would like to use just one function.

Comment: I rewrote the answer to use `$request->validate` instead. This might suite you.

Comment: Combining your suggestion with @Sletheren gives me an idea. Thank you to you both.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom request:

```
php artisan make:request CustomRequest
```

This will generate this class:

```
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

The `authorize()` method will determine if the request can be validated in the first place.

The `rules()` method will return the validation rules for the current request.

And then in your controller function:

```
public function yourfunction(CustomRequest $request)
```

Comment: Hi @Sletheren, yes I know this. What I want to do is to validate a dynamic set of data. For example, Set of data1 required fields are firstname,middlename,lastname, then data2 required fields are firstname,lastname only. So what I have in mind is I would create data1Request and data2Request.

Comment: yes you can do that as well, you put a generic Request object, and then test  with an if statement (example: if($request['type'] == 'data1') then execute a custom validation

Comment: Well, got some idea with what you've said. Thank you @Sletheren

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1 Make a Trait**

```
 public function store(Request $req)
{
    $model = (new $this->modelClass);

    $this->_modiformRequest($model, $req);

    $this->_makevalidateform($req);

    $savedModel = $this->_save($req, $model);

        return redirect()->route('web.dashboard'));
}

 protected function _modiformRequest($model, Request &$request)
{
    //
}

 protected function _rules($request, $id = null): array
{
    return [];
}


 protected function _makevalidateform($request, $id = null)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->_rules($request, $id), $this->_ruleMessages($request, $id), $this->_ruleAttributes($request, $id));
}
```

**Step-2 Make a controller**

```
 protected function _rules($request, $id = null): array
    {
        if ($id) {
            return [
                'first_name' => 'required',
                'last_name' => 'required',
            ];
        }

        return [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

In the validation rules you can simply add the "sometimes" rule. You can find it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

```
   public function rules()
{
    return [
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'middlename' => 'sometimes|required',
    'lastname' => 'required'
    ];
}
```